# How to use flutter provider in a statefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using flutter_provider for state management. I want to load some items on page(statefulwidget) load from Api. I am showing a loader on page start and want to show the items once they are fetched.

PlayList.dart -

```
class Playlist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaylistState createState() => _PlaylistState();
}

class _PlaylistState extends State<Playlist> {
var videosState;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     videosState = Provider.of<VideosProvider>(context);
    videosState.fetchVideosList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var videos = videosState.playlist;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Videos'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: videos.length
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    return _videoListItem(context, index, videos, videosState);
                  },
                  itemCount: videos.length,
                )
              : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
        ),
        onRefresh: () => null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My provider is like this -

```
class VideosProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  List _playlist;
  int _currentVideoId;  
  get playlist => _playlist;

  void setPlayList(videosList) {
    _playlist = videosList;
  }

  Future fetchVideosList() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("http://192.168.1.22:3000/videos-list/");

    print(json.decode(response.body));
    videos = json.decode(response.body)["data"];
    setPlayList(videos);
    return videos;
  }
}
```

This gives an error of -

```
inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_Provider<VideosProvider>) or inheritFromElement() was called before _PlaylistState.initState() completed.
```

here is the build method of the parent of playList class, wrapped in a changenotifier,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<VideosProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => VideosProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "My App",
        home: new Playlist(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So, all the examples on flutter_provider on internet show usage of provider on a statelesswidget, where state changes occur on user interactions like a button click. None about how to use provider in a statefulWidget, and cases where data has to be updated on page load without any interaction.

I am aware of streambuilder and futurebuilder for this kind of scenarios, but want to understand how this can be done with flutter_provider. How can I use provider to call fetchVideosList in initState(on pageload)? Does this case can/should be handled with a statelessWidget?

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-architecture-provider-implementation-guide-d33133a9a4e8) might be a good read.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927789/stateful-widget-inside-an-provider-changenotifier-widget-does-not-get-updated), (different error), which is now solved.

Answer (score 18):

> Does this case can/should be handled with a statelessWidget?

The answer is : **No, it does not**

I am heavy user of StatefulWidget + Provider. I always use this pattern for displaying a Form which contains fields, that available for future edit or input.

**Updated : February 9 2020**

Regarding to Maks comment, I shared better way to manage provider using didChangeDependencies.

[image: Demo]

You may check to this [github repository](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_list_view_provider)

**main.dart**

1. First Step

Initiate PlayListScreen inside ChangeNotifierProvider

```dart
class PlaylistScreenProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<VideosProvider>(
      create: (_) {
        return VideosProvider();
      },
      child: PlaylistScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go To StatefulWidget Screen"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) {
                  return PlaylistScreenProvider();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. Second Step

Make PlaylistScreen as Stateful Widget to hold TextEditingContoller
and other values.

**playlistScreen.dart**

```dart
class PlaylistScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaylistScreenState createState() => _PlaylistScreenState();
}

class _PlaylistScreenState extends State<PlaylistScreen> {
  List _playlistList;
  String _errorMessage;
  Stage _stage;

  final _searchTextCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _searchTextCtrl.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final videosState = Provider.of<VideosProvider>(context);
    _playlistList = videosState.playlist;
    _stage = videosState.stage;
    _errorMessage = videosState.errorMessage;
  }

  void actionSearch() {
    String text = _searchTextCtrl.value.text;
    Provider.of<VideosProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .updateCurrentVideoId(text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Videos'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: Text("Filter"),
                onPressed: () {
                  actionSearch();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _searchTextCtrl,
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  actionSearch();
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Please input 1 or 2',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: _stage == Stage.DONE
                  ? PlaylistTree(_playlistList)
                  : _stage == Stage.ERROR
                      ? Center(child: Text("$_errorMessage"))
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlaylistTree extends StatelessWidget {
  PlaylistTree(this.playlistList);

  final List playlistList;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: playlistList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var data = playlistList[index];
        return Container(
          child: Text("${data['id']} - ${data['first_name']}"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

3. Last Step

make provider to handle Business Logic

**videosProvider.dart**

```dart
enum Stage { ERROR, LOADING, DONE }

class VideosProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String errorMessage = "Network Error";
  Stage stage;
  List _playlist;
  int _currentVideoId;

  VideosProvider() {
    this.stage = Stage.LOADING;
    initScreen();
  }

  void initScreen() async {
    try {
      await fetchVideosList();
      stage = Stage.DONE;
    } catch (e) {
      stage = Stage.ERROR;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List get playlist => _playlist;

  void setPlayList(videosList) {
    _playlist = videosList;
  }

  void validateInput(String valueText) {
    if (valueText == ""){
      this._currentVideoId = null;
      return;
    }
    try {
      int valueInt = int.parse(valueText);
      if (valueInt == 1 || valueInt == 2){
        this._currentVideoId = valueInt;
      }
      else {
        this.errorMessage = "Use only 1 and 2";
        throw 1;
      }
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      this.errorMessage = "Must be a number";
      throw 1;
    }
  }

  void updateCurrentVideoId(String value) async {
    this.stage = Stage.LOADING;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      validateInput(value);
      await fetchVideosList();
      stage = Stage.DONE;
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      this.errorMessage = "Network Error";
      stage = Stage.ERROR;
    } catch (e) {
      stage = Stage.ERROR;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future fetchVideosList() async {
    String url;
    if (_currentVideoId != null) {
      url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=$_currentVideoId";
    } else {
      url = "https://reqres.in/api/users";
    }
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var videosList = json.decode(response.body)["data"];
    setPlayList(videosList);
  }
}
```

**Old answer : Aug 19 2019**

### In my case :

**form_screen.dart**

```dart
class Form extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<FormProvider>(
      builder: (_) {
        return FormProvider(id: ...); // Passing Provider to child widget
      },
      child: FormWidget(), // So Provider.of<FormProvider>(context) can be read here
    );
  }
}


class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormWidgetState createState() => _FormWidgetState();
}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // No need to override initState like your code

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var formState = Provider.of<FormProvider>(context) // access any provided data
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ....
    );
  }
}
```

FormProvider as a class, need to update their latest value from API. So, **initially**, it will request to some URL and updates corresponding values.

**form_provider.dart**

```dart
class FormProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DocumentModel document;
  int id;

  FormProvider({@required int id}) {
    this.id = id;
    initFormFields(); // will perform network request
  }

  void initFormFields() async {
    Map results = initializeDataFromApi(id: id);
    try {
      document = DocumentModel.fromJson(results['data']);
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle Exceptions
    }
    notifyListeners(); // triggers FormWidget to re-execute build method for second time
  }
```

### In your case :

**PlayList.dart**

```dart
class PlaylistScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<VideosProvider>(
      builder: (_) {
        return VideosProvider(); // execute construct method and fetchVideosList asynchronously
      },
      child: Playlist(),
    );
  }
}


class Playlist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaylistState createState() => _PlaylistState();
}

class _PlaylistState extends State<Playlist> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // We *moved* this to build method
    // videosState = Provider.of<VideosProvider>(context);

    // We *moved* this to constructor method in provider
    // videosState.fetchVideosList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Moved from initState
    var videosState = Provider.of<VideosProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Videos'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
  }
}
```

**provider.dart**

```dart
class VideosProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  VideosProvider() {
    // *moved* from Playlist.initState()
    fetchVideosList(); // will perform network request
  }

  List _playlist;
  int _currentVideoId;  
  get playlist => _playlist;

  void setPlayList(videosList) {
    _playlist = videosList;
  }

  Future fetchVideosList() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get("http://192.168.1.22:3000/videos-list/");

    print(json.decode(response.body));
    videos = json.decode(response.body)["data"];
    setPlayList(videos);
    // return videos; // no need to return

    // We need to notify Playlist widget to rebuild itself for second time
    notifyListeners(); // mandatory
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not the recommended way to access a Provider within a stateful widget, instead you should be accessing `Provider.of()` inside an overrriden  `didChangeDependencies()`

Comment: I see.. Then should I move videosState variable in build method to be a property/field of Playlist Class ?

Comment: No a field of `_PlaylistState` class and you would set it using `Provider.of()` within `didChangeDependencies()`

Answer (score 5):

When using Provider for state management you don't need to use StatefullWidget, so how can you call a method of the ChangeNotifier on start of the app?

You can simply do that in the constructor of the ChangeNotifier, so that when you point out VideosProvider() to the ChangeNotifierProvider Builder the constructor will get called the first time the provider constructs the VideosProvider, so:

PlayList.dart:

```
class Playlist extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final videosState = Provider.of<VideosProvider>(context);
  var videos = videosState.playlist;
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My Videos'),
    ),
    body: RefreshIndicator(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: videos.length
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return _videoListItem(context, index, videos, videosState);
                },
                itemCount: videos.length,
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
      onRefresh: () => null,
    ),
  );
```

}
}

VideosProvider.dart:

```
class VideosProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  VideosProvider(){
    fetchVideosList();
  }

  List _playlist;
  int _currentVideoId;  
  get playlist => _playlist;

  void setPlayList(videosList) {
     _playlist = videosList;
  }

  Future fetchVideosList() async {
    http.Response response =
    await http.get("http://192.168.1.22:3000/videos-list/");

    print(json.decode(response.body));
    videos = json.decode(response.body)["data"];
    setPlayList(videos);
    return videos;
 }
```

}

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But is this the best way to do this? Also, I cannot get this working with Multiprovider `MultiProvider(
      providers: [
               Provider<VideosProvider>.value(value:videosProvider)//instance of VideosProvider
      ],child:...)`. The widget is never re-rendered, even though notifyListeners is being called. I do not know if the problem is with my code or this approach.

Comment: Ok, I got it working with `MultiProvider(
      providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<VideosModel>(builder: (BuildContext context)=>videosModel,)
      ],child:...`. so we need to use `changeNotifierProvider` for changes to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

When using a Provider you don’t need to use a `StatefulWidget` (as of a tutorial by the Flutter team [State management](https://youtu.be/8II1VPb-neQ)

You may use the following tutorial to see how to fetch data with a provider and a
StatelessWidget: [Flutter StateManagement with Provider](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-statemanagement-with-provider-ee251bbc5ac1)

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question to be more clear. As I said, all the resources I could find, like the ones you provided, only explain scenarios of state update on user interaction, but none about state changes on page load. May be this is where streamprovider is used?

Comment: @NDM - Mobile DEV, supposed I need to create a form in a page, I still don't need a StatefulWidget ?  I meant, the provider can help with forms too?