# Data gets loaded only when the page rebuilds or app reloads - Provider

Tags: flutter

I've implemented Provider pattern in a simple Notes app.

### Problem :

Data is loaded on the screen only when the app reloads or the screen gets rebuilt.

This is my `note_list` stateless widget which displays the notes :

```dart
class NoteList extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Note List"),
      ),
      body: getnoteListView(context),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return ChangeNotifierProvider(
              builder: (context) => NoteProvider(),
              child: NoteDetail(Note('', '', 2), 'Add Note'),
            );
          }));
        },
        tooltip: "Add Note",
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView getnoteListView(BuildContext context) {      // <---- the thing to be focused here
    final noteProvider = Provider.of<NoteProvider>(context);
    var noteList = noteProvider.noteList;
    var count = noteList.length;
    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        print(noteList[index].title);
        return Text(
          noteList[index].title,
          style: titleStyle,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And the `NoteProvider.dart` :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pass_list/models/note.dart';
import 'package:pass_list/utils/database_helper.dart';

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713184
class NoteProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  List<Note> _noteList = [];
  int count = 0;
  // get updateListView;

get noteList => _noteList;

  NoteProvider(){
    fetchNotes();
  }

  void setNoteList(notesList) {
     _noteList = notesList;
// notifyListeners(); <- this didn't work either
  }

  fetchNotes() async {
    await databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    List<Note> noteList = await databaseHelper.getNoteList();
    setNoteList(noteList);  
  }

  Future<int> updateNote(note) async{
    var result = await databaseHelper.updateNote(note);
    await fetchNotes();
    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> insertNote(note) async{
    var result =  await databaseHelper.insertNote(note);
    await fetchNotes();
    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(noteId) async{
    var result =  await databaseHelper.deleteNote(noteId);
    await fetchNotes();
    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Here's the repo, in case you wish to run the app : [Repo](https://github.com/LuD1161/notes_app)

Directory Structure :

```dart
lib
├── main.dart
├── models
│   └── note.dart
├── screens
│   ├── note_detail.dart
│   └── note_list.dart
└── utils
    ├── database_helper.dart
    └── NoteProvider.dart
```

### Video of the problem : https://youtu.be/YrAVTum9P6E

### Update :

Since in the constructor for noteProvider I've fetchNotes so maybe due to that, when the app is loaded it's being fetched and due to that I added in all other functions too. But that didn't end as expected and am still facing the error.

### Help with design and best practices

Moreover it would be better if someone could point to me some resources like blog/actual code where I can see this implemented. That would be really awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: So the question is how should the provider fetch data from the database to display to the user ?